# Nginx regex's aren't matching properly

Tags: nginx

I've got a pretty basic `nginx/nginx.conf` but unfortunately I can't get 1 of the servers to match properly, I'm pretty sure it's because they use some text which is exactly the same as another domain

I've tested the regex's on regex101.com and they seem to be matching the way they should be, but nginx is doing something else with them

this is what my whole nginx conf looks like

https://pastebin.com/E3N8awGk

key area:

```
# lopudesigns
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     ~^(.*|)(\.|)lopudesigns\.dev$;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header  x-real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            # proxy_set_header    Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header    Connection              $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    host                    $host;
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:7777;
        }
    }
    # lopudesigns example sites
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     ~^ozledgrowlights\.lopudesigns\.dev$;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header  x-real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            # proxy_set_header    Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header    Connection              $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    host                    $host;
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        }
    }
    # ozledgrowlights
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     ~^(.*|)(\.|)ozledgrowlights\.dev\.au$;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header  x-real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            # proxy_set_header    Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header    Connection              $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    host                    $host;
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        }
    }
    # a lopu client
    server {
        listen               80;
        server_name         ~^(.*|)(\.|)alopu\.com$;
        return 301          https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         ~^(.*|)(\.|)alopu\.com$;
        keepalive_timeout   70;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header  x-real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection              $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    host                    $host;
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        }
        ssl_certificate         /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/alopu/server.crt.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/alopu/server.key.pem;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout     10m;

    }
```

ozledgrowlights.dev.au matches correctly

alopu.com matches correctly

but lopudesigns.dev gets proxied to http://127.0.0.1:8888 instead of http://127.0.0.1:7777

which is evident because the url doesn't change, so it doesn't actually get redirected to alopu.com, which means that the alopu.com regex/server block is capturing those http requests, which is pretty weird since the regex

`~^(.*|)(\.|)lopudesigns\.dev$;` captures `lopudesigns.dev` perfectly and `~^(.*|)(\.|)alopu\.com$;` doesn't capture `lopudesigns.dev` at all

I should also note that `~^(.*|)(\.|)ozledgrowlights\.dev\.au$;` doesn't capture anything at all, so `ozledgrowlights.lopudesigns.dev` doesn't load anything at all

so I'm a bit confused? :O

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it was some local issue with the .dev domain, not sure what it was but changing .dev to .ved made it work... odd